# How do I verify a tweepy API using 3 legged auth?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I've been following the instructions in the tweepy documentation:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html

When I pass in an oauth_verifier to get a user's access tokens, it throws out:

tweepy.errors.TweepyException: 'oauth_token'

```
@views.route("/")
def home():
    with open("oauth1_user_handler", "rb") as userHandler:
        oauth1_user_handler=pickle.load(userHandler)
    oauth_verifier = request.args.get("oauth_verifier")
    user_access_token, user_access_token_secret = oauth1_user_handler.get_access_token(
        oauth_verifier
    )
    return "<p>user_access_token, user_access_token_secret</p>."
```

I've tried multiple variations of passing in the oauth_verifier, the oauth_token, and combinations of the 2, exactly as they are in the url parameters, but that hasn't worked either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reinitializing `OAuth1UserHandler` and not using the same instance, you need to set the request token and secret before using the verifier to get the access token and secret.

There's a section on this in the documentation you linked: https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.10.1/authentication.html#legged-oauth

Comment: I did try that, but the following line convinced me I was missing something:

`request_token = oauth1_user_handler.request_token["oauth_token"]`

Returns KeyError: 'oauth_token' no matter how i try implement that one line.

Comment: Show that relevant code, where you first initialize it.

Comment: `oauth1_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
        config["twitter"]["api_key"], config["twitter"]["api_key_secret"],
        callback="http://127.0.0.1:5000/login"
    )
    request_token = oauth1_user_handler.request_token["oauth_token"]
    request_secret = oauth1_user_handler.request_token["oauth_token_secret"]
    if request.args.get("oauth_verifier") == None:
        return f"<a href={oauth1_user_handler.get_authorization_url(signin_with_twitter=True)}>Log in with twitter </a>"`

It seems like quite simple code

Comment: You need to get the authorization URL first, as there's no way for the handler to have the token and secret before any request is even made. In the future, for multiple lines of code, please edit your post instead of including it in a comment.